# VBA - Userform - Loop - if Label have text

Tags: vba

Hi all How can I make a statement if label have text And TextBox have no text in a loop? I can't find anything about it I know with a textbox I can use the .TextLength but that don't work as .CaptionLength Hope you can help

```
For k = 2 To 41
   If Me.Controls("Label" & k).CaptionLength < 0 And Me.Controls("TextBox" & 
   k).TextLength = 0 Then
   MsgBox "You have a name without Hdc"

   Exit Sub
 End If
```

UPDATED With working Code

```
Dim k As Long
For k = 1 To 40
    If Len(Me.Controls("Label" & k).Caption) > 0 And Me.Controls("TextBox" & 
k).Text = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "You have a name without Hdc"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
If len(Me.Controls("Label" & k).caption) > 0 And ...
```

The `len` function returns the length of a string and the `caption`-property gives the text (caption) of a label

Comment: Hmm I think its on the right track but it is bring up the msgbox even though there is no empty TextBox is it because I use the textbox wrong I tried using = and <> for the textbox also without closing with ()

`If Len(Me.Controls("Label" & k).Caption) > 0 And (Me.Controls("TextBox" & k).TextLength <> 0) Then`

Comment: let me try with using len on textbox too

Comment: For the textbox, you can use the property `text` (not caption), but `TextLength` should work also. But if you want to check if the textbox is empty, you have to check for `TextLength = 0`

Comment: Now its working EPIC thanks so much for your help much appreciated !